# What is an equivalent to Gazebo 9 function physics::Joint::Position() in Gazebo 7 for prismatic joint?

Tags: gazebo-7

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I was using the physics::Joint::Position() function in Gazebo 9 to get the deflection of the child link from its initial position. Now I want to implement the same in Gazebo 7, but it doesn't have this function and I can't find anything in the [API documentation](http://osrf-distributions.s3.amazonaws.com/gazebo/api/7.1.0/classgazebo_1_1physics_1_1Joint.html), that looks like it does the same thing.

What can I use to get the deflection of the prismatic joint in Gazebo 7?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/21723/what-is-an-equivalent-to-gazebo-9-function-physics::joint::position()-in-gazebo-7-for-prismatic-joint?/) by [kumpakri](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6511/kumpakri/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 755 on 2019-01-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

It's called `GetAngle()`. Note that this function accepts an argument representing the index of the axis. In a prismatic joint, you'll use `0`.  See [here](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/d3165fd7143da7d2ec9062ce4660306a3f243dd5/gazebo/physics/Joint.hh?at=gazebo7&fileviewer=file-view-default#Joint.hh-354) for the function definition.

---

Originally posted by [Carlos Agüero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/280/carlos-ag%C3%BCero/) with karma: 626 on 2019-01-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kumpakri](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6511/kumpakri/) on 2019-01-16**:
I was thinking about that, but the function returns an angle. How do I map this value to the prismatic joint deflection from initial position in meters?

**Comment by [Carlos Agüero](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/280/carlos-ag%C3%BCero/) on 2019-01-16**:
The name of the function is confusing and that's why we deprecated it. It will actually return a position if you're using a prismatic joint.